# PHP security concerns around in clause that is a concatenated string

Tags: php, sql, security

Given the following [code](http://ideone.com/Fsdofw)

```
 <?php
$values = array('Foo'  =>'Foo'  ,'Bar'  =>'Bar'  );
$separated = "'" . implode("','", $values)."'";
$sql = 'SELECT NAME,AGE FROM CATS WHERE TITLE IN('  .$separated.')'  ;

print_r($sql);
```

produces:

```
 SELECT NAME,AGE FROM CATS WHERE TITLE IN('Foo','Bar')
```

Is there anything I need to be aware of about SQL injection using this type of query builder?  If so, what is an attack that can occur?

Comment: It depends where `$values` comes from and whether it's been sanitised.

Comment: @Spudley right agree, have an example of a "dangerous" area?

Comment: Not necessarily injection, but the strings inside `$values` could break your query, e.g. `Foo's`

Comment: NEVER TRUST DATA COMING FROM A USER.

Answer (score 2):

The only rule of SQL security:

#### NO value should be added to a query directly, but via placeholder only

So, you have to use a library that supports placeholders.

Assuming your database is mysql, the best choice would be [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql), which will let you have as simple code as this:

```
$sql  = 'SELECT NAME,AGE FROM CATS WHERE TITLE IN(?a)';
$data = $db->getArr($sql, $values);
print_r($data);
```

or you can use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info), but it will take you [a lot more trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991146/285587)

Comment: I use PDO and have a setup like this: `$result = $this->db->query('SELECT FROM users WHERE id IN (' . $this->getPlaceholders($userIds) . ')', $userIds);` Where the function just returns `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'))` or `null`

Comment: See, it is much worse than safeMysql's custom placeholders, isn't it? ;) But for the PDO world your solution is nearly brilliant though

Comment: Yep, easier is (almost) always better :) Just wanted to share it in case OP (or others) were bound to PDO as I am and wanted a solution. Oh, and any improvement suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You could make it an answer, and it will be a good one. Think of the future readers. A nicely formatted answer contains all the code and example is better than sketch in the comments.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant as an answer, OP never said he was using PDO :)

Comment: @JimL feel free to make it an answer, future readers dont tend to focus on comments too much and i am going to try the PDO version as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use any variables in queries no matter where they come from. A solution for PDO and parameterized queries will be to add placeholders to the query.

I do it something like this:

```
function getPlaceholders ($array) {
  return !empty($array)
    ? implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'))
    : null;
}

$userIds = array(1,2,3,4);

$sql = 'SELECT FROM users WHERE id IN (' . $this->getPlaceholders($userIds) . ')';
$result = pdo_query($sql, $userIds);
```

---

Normally you would have this in a OOP-format.

```
$userIds = array(1,2,3,4);

$sql = 'SELECT FROM users WHERE id IN (' . $this->getPlaceholders($userIds) . ')';
$result = $this->db->query($sql, $userIds);


// common file which is extended
public function getPlaceholders ($array) {
  return !empty($array)
    ? implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'))
    : null;
}
```

---

This will generate a query like:

```
SELECT FROM users WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Just a note. Sadly, but for `NOT IN (NULL)` it will return no records as well as `IN (NULL)`, while I would expect rather opposite behavior. It bugs me a little but no solution has been found yet